# Can't get right-side margin to work on grid-based fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

I've created a sticky top navbar which is working fine. I have added margin of 15vw to the left side logo image and I'm trying to do the same on the right but it won't work and I don't know why. I'm sure it's a simple solution but I'm new to this!

HTML:

```
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
   <nav class="navbar">
     <a class="nav-logo" href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1LnAM3W.png" title="Home" height="50px"></a>
     <b class="filler"></b>
     <a id="about-us" class="nav-link" href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
     <a id="our-mentors" class="nav-link active" href="our_mentors.html">Our Mentors<a/>
     <a id="bookings" class="nav-link" href="bookings.html">Bookings</a>
     <a id="contact" class="nav-link" href="contact_us.html">Contact</a>
   </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 55px;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr max-content max-content max-content max-content;
  grid-template-areas: "nav-logo filler about-us our-mentors bookings contact-us";
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-logo {
  grid-area: "nav-logo";
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 15vw;
}

.filler        { grid-area: filler;
                 background: white }
#about-us      { grid-area: about-us }
#our-mentors   { grid-area: our-mentors }
#bookings      { grid-area: bookings }
#contact-us    { grid-area: contact-us;
                 margin-right: 15vw }
```

The "contact-us" is the grid item on the far right but the margin won't apply to it like it does the logo. Also, I'm not using a bootstrap either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id for your contact link isn't the correct one used in your css, try put id="contact-us" in your HTML or #contact in your css and it should work !